# Swift NSSortDescriptor: Sorting alphabetically, start at other letter than "A"

Tags: swift, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I want to sort alphabetically but starting with another letter than "A". And then wrapping around when the sort reaches "Z". So that means for example starting at "E":

E, F, G, H... Z, A, B, C, D

The normal sort descriptor is

```
NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \MyData.dataDetail, ascending: true)
```

How can I change the sort descriptor to allow for this functionality?

Comment: Why do you need a `NSSortDescriptor`?

Comment: You can create a sort descriptor that uses a custom sort method or comparator, see the documentation. I believe that is probably the best way forward

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use comparators block with Core Data so it crashes on me. Any other ideas? Thanks :-)

Comment: How are you using the results of the fetch? In a tableView?

Comment: Yes ising it  in a tableView. I’m really stuck with this problem…

Comment: It might be possible to achieve what you want with a bit of a hack - adjusting your datasource indices to give your TV indexPaths and vice versa.  If you edit your question to show your TV cellForRowAt code, I’ll take a look.

Comment: can you do do two fetches, one for all entities before E, and one for all entities after E and then combine them in the collectionView?

Comment: Thanks for the tips, they got me thinking laterally! In Swift I believe these solutions would be perfect. I am using SwiftUI so I directly loop through the fetch results. I think the only way is a workaround by first converting to an array in .onAppear, changing the sort order of the array  and then to loop through the array.